# OpenVPN website secure connection Error

Tags: windows, openvpn

I want to download the `OpenVPN` Client from [openvpn.org](http://openvpn.org), but I get an error:

*This site can’t provide a secure connection

swupdate.openvpn.org uses an unsupported protocol.

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH*

I found a source to download the `.msi` client file, but it doesn't specify which OS it supports - I need both windows `32-bit` and `64-bit`. Can anyone provide a mirror for those files, please?

Regards,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows `32bit`: http://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-install-2.3.10-I002-i686.exe

For Windows `64bit`: http://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-install-2.3.10-I002-x86_64.exe

Comment: My pleasure @Jack